# Trying to get the output of a vgg16 model throws error asking to use keras model get_output_at

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have created a modified convolutional neural network which includes `keras vgg16` and I would like to get the output of the last VGG16 layer (which is the one before the layers I've added), but when I do that the following error is thrown:

Creating the Neural Network:

```
def get_vgg16_model(input_shape, y_flat):
    vgg16model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False,
                       input_shape=input_shape)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(vgg16model)
    # I want to get the output from above this comment
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.summary()
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.5, nesterov=True)  # was 'adam'

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc'])
    return model

...

    # input placeholder
    inp = model.input
    # getting the output to all layers, we are only interested in vgg16's
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
    # evaluation function
    functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs)
    layer_outs = functor([X, 1]) 

...

    elif config.mode == 'vgg16':
        # output of vgg16
        return layer_outs[1]
```

This returns, when run with the appropriate input:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 999, 32, 3)        12        
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 31, 1, 512)        14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 31, 1, 64)         32832     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 31, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1984)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                19850     
=================================================================
Total params: 14,767,382
Trainable params: 14,767,376
Non-trainable params: 6
_________________________________________________________________

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\aaaa.py", line 210, in solrSearch
    tmp = featureExtractor(X=X_ill_temp, config=config, y=y_ill_temp)
  File "F:\aaaa.py", line 362, in featureExtractor
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
  File "F:\aaaa.py", line 362, in <listcomp>
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
  File "F:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 845, in output
    ' has multiple inbound nodes, '
AttributeError: Layer vgg16 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead.
```

I have also implemented a convolutional neural network with `keras layers` and used the same method to obtain intermediate outputs, but in that case no error is thrown.

Now, my questions is, how do I use get_output_at by modifying the `layer_outs` code?